# Как посчитать количество выполненных шагов в цикле?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double x0;
        double y0;
        bool tb1 = false;
        bool tb2 = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void xTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Double.TryParse(xTextBox.Text.Replace('.', ','), out x0))
            {
                xTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                tb1 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                xTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                tb1 = false;
            }
            CheckFields();
        }

        private void CheckFields()
        {
            if (tb1 && tb2)
                button.Enabled = true;
            else
                button.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void yTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Double.TryParse(yTextBox.Text.Replace('.', ','), out y0))
            {
                yTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                tb2 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                yTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                tb2 = false;
            }
            CheckFields();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xTextBox_TextChanged(sender, e);
            yTextBox_TextChanged(sender, e);
            Plotting();
            chart1.Series[2].Points.Clear();
            double eps = 0.001;
            double xn, yn;
            double err = 2 * eps;
            while (err >= eps)
            {
                yn = F(x0);
                xn = G(y0);
                err = Math.Abs(xn - x0) + Math.Abs(yn - y0);
                chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(x0, y0);
                x0 = xn;
                y0 = yn;
            }
            xrTextBox.Text = x0.ToString();
            yrTextBox.Text = y0.ToString();
        }

        private double F(double x)
        {
            return 0.8 - Math.Cos(x - 1);
        }

        private double G(double y)
        {
            return 2 + Math.Cos(y);
        }

        private void Plotting()
        {
            double xa = 1;
            double xb = 4;

            int n = 1000;
            double h = (xb - xa) / (n - 1);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                double x = xa + i * h;
                double y = F(x);
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
            }


            double ya = -1;
            double yb = 2;
            h = (yb - ya) / (n - 1);
            chart1.Series[1].Points.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                double y = ya + i * h;
                double x = G(y);
                chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x, y);
            }
        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите посчитать количество шагов в данном цикле

```
while (err >= eps)
```

То вам нужно вне этого цикла завести переменную-счетчик, и инициализировать ее нулем. Далее в начале каждой итерации увеличивать этот счетчик на единицу.

```
int counter = 0;
while (err >= eps)
{
    counter+=1;
    // Остальной код
}
```

После выполнения цикла вы можете вывести переменную counter туда, куда вам нужно, так же помните об областях видимости переменных, если захотите использовать ее где-то в другой функции.В следующий раз желательно лучше формулировать вопрос, конкретно показывать в каком куске кода вам нужно что-то сделать и самым правильным решением будет сначала гуглить, а потом лезть в SO